# Symbolic solution of an iterative system

Tags: differential-equations, linear-algebra, symbolic, finite-difference-method

I am not an expert in Mathematica. I want to keep off from tedious calculation

I want to solve (in symbolic sens) this system: $\quad AU^{j+1}+BU^{j}=F^{j}$

where:

$*$ ${U}^{j}$ a $(N;1)$ vector $\quad\mathbf{U}^{j}=\left[\begin{array}{c}u_{1}^{j} \\ \vdots \\ u_{N}^{j}\end{array}\right]$ and $\quad\mathbf{U}^{1}=\left[\begin{array}{c}\phi(x_{2}) \\ \phi(x_{2}) \\\phi(x_{3}) \\ \vdots \\ \phi(x_{N-1}) \\ \phi(x_{N-1})\end{array}\right] $

$*$ ${F}^{j}$ a $(N-2;1)$ vector$\quad\mathbf{F}^{j}=\left[\begin{array}{c}kf_{2}^{j} \\ \vdots \\ kf_{N-1}^{j}\end{array}\right] $

$*$ $A$ a $(N-2;N)$ matrix $A=\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
-\lambda &-1& -\lambda&0&0&\cdots&0\\
0&-\lambda &-1& -\lambda&0&\cdots&0\\
0&0&-\lambda &-1& -\lambda&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&0&\cdots&-1&-\lambda\\
\end{array}\right)$

$*$ $B$ a $(N-2;N)$ matrix $B=\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
0&1&0&0&\cdots&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&\cdots&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&\cdots&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\\
0&0&0&\cdots&0&1&0\\
\end{array}\right)$

Thanks a lot for your time, you can ask me to clarify anything

Comment: For explicit `n`, `U1`, and some closed for expression for the  `Fj` you might be able to use `RSolve`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll try it now

Comment: would you please explain bit more? I'm trying with RSolve butstill can't get results

Comment: It would help if you post an explicit (and small) example. This requires explicit forms of UU1 and the F vectors.

Comment: the vector $U^{1}$  and $F^{j}$ are supposed known, and I  need to determine explicitly $u_{1}^{2}, u_{2}^{2}, \cdots , u_{N}^{2}, u_{1}^{3}, \cdots \cdots u_{N-1}^{K},.u_{N}^{K},$

Comment: Is $A$ a $(N-2)\times N$ matrix? How is it possible?

Comment: yes it is, we have $\quad AU^{j+1}+BU^{j}=F^{j}$  i.e $(N-2,N) \times (N,1) + (N-2,N) \times (N,1) =  (N-2,1) \quad  $ this is the reduced form, but if we expand the vectors $U^{j}$ and $F^{j}$ for $j=1, \cdots K-1$  , w'll get an equivalent bloc system $\quad A_{b}U_{b1}+B_{b}U_{b0}=F_{b}$ the little $b$ mean bloc and $U_{b1}=(u_{1}^{1}, u_{2}^{1}, \cdots , u_{N}^{1}, u_{1}^{2}, \cdots \cdots u_{N-1}^{K-1},.u_{N}^{K-1}),$ and $U_{b0}=(u_{1}^{2}, u_{2}^{2}, \cdots , u_{N}^{2}, u_{1}^{3}, \cdots \cdots u_{N-1}^{K},.u_{N}^{K})$ and $F_{b}=k(f_{2}^{1}, f_{3}^{1} , \cdots  f_{N}^{K-1})$,

Comment: I hope you get the idea, I we'll need pages to write the solution by myself that what I need to use the programme

Comment: Correct then the $A$ definition because it is represented as a square matrix. Look at the diagonal.

Comment: The same occurs with $B$ matrix.

Comment: Thank you, you're right

Comment: If this is a recurrent relation, what is $U_0$? If it is expected to be a fixed point convergent process, we can solve that.

Comment: the iterations change as follow: $i=1,2 \cdots, N$ and $j=1,2 \cdots, K$. The first vector is $U^{1}$ ie $j=1$ and is defined as showed above. this vector we'll help us to get the explicit expression of $U^{2}$ and next we express $U^{3}$ by the element of $U^{2}$ i.e $u_{1}^{2}, u_{2}^{2}, \cdots , u_{N}^{2}$

Comment: Oops, didn't fully read the question.

Answer (score 2):

My intention is to share some ideas that can help in solving the problem.

Calling

$$
U_k = \left[ \mathbb{U}_k \ | \ \mathbb{U}_k^0\right]\\
A = \left[ \mathbb{A}\  |\  \mathbb{A}_0\right]\\
B = \left[ \mathbb{B} \ | \ \mathbb{B}_0\right]\\
$$

then

$$
A U_{k+1}+B U_k = F_k\Leftrightarrow \mathbb{A}\mathbb{U}_{k+1}+\mathbb{B}\mathbb{U}_k+\mathbb{A_0}\mathbb{U^0}_{k+1}+\mathbb{B_0}\mathbb{U^0}_k = F_k
$$

so we can ask for solutions where

$$
\cases{\mathbb{A}\mathbb{U}_{k+1}+\mathbb{B}\mathbb{U}_k = F_k\\
\mathbb{A_0}\mathbb{U^0}_{k+1}+\mathbb{B_0}\mathbb{U^0}_k = 0
}
$$

and for $m = n+2 = 4+2=6$ we have

$$
\cases{ \mathbb{A}=\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 -\lambda  & -1 & -\lambda  & 0 \\
 0 & -\lambda  & -1 & -\lambda  \\
 0 & 0 & -\lambda  & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -\lambda  \\
\end{array}
\right],\ \ \mathbb{A}_0 = \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 -\lambda  & 0 \\
 -1 & -\lambda  \\
\end{array}
\right]\\
\mathbb{B} = \left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right], \ \mathbb{B}_0 = \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]\\
\mathbb{U} = \{u_1,\cdots,u_4\},\ \mathbb{U_0} = \{u_5,u_6\}
}
$$

now  $\mathbb{A},\ \mathbb{B}$ commute so we can develop some equivalent recurrences: from

$$
\mathbb{A}^2\mathbb{U}_{k+1}+\mathbb{A}\mathbb{B}\mathbb{U}_k = \mathbb{A}F_k\\
\mathbb{B}\mathbb{A}\mathbb{U}_{k}+\mathbb{B}^2\mathbb{U}_{k-1} = \mathbb{B}F_{k-1}
$$

we have

$$
\mathbb{A}^2\mathbb{U}_{k+1}-\mathbb{B}^2\mathbb{U}_{k-1} = \mathbb{A}F_k-\mathbb{B}F_{k-1}
$$

and proceeding

$$
\mathbb{A}^4\mathbb{U}_{k+1}-\mathbb{A}^2\mathbb{B}^2\mathbb{U}_{k-1} = \mathbb{A}^3F_k-\mathbb{A}^2\mathbb{B}F_{k-1}\\
\mathbb{B}^2\mathbb{A}^2\mathbb{U}_{k-1}-\mathbb{B}^4\mathbb{U}_{k-2} = \mathbb{B}^2\mathbb{A}F_{k-1}-\mathbb{B}^3F_{k-2}
$$

or

$$
\mathbb{A}^4\mathbb{U}_{k+1}-\mathbb{B}^4\mathbb{U}_{k-2} = \cdots 
$$

note that $\mathbb{B}^n = 0$

etc.

NOTE

In MATHEMATICA you can represent $A$ and $B$ as follows

```
n = 6;
A = -Table[If[i == j, lambda, If[i + 1 == j, 1, If[i + 2 == j, lambda, 0]]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n + 2}];
B = Table[If[i + 1 == j, 1, 0], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n + 2}];
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your insights. I don't have now comment on your approach since I'm a newbie in Mathematica, but you have shown me where I need to start to tackle this kind of problem.